# What change from PHP version 5.2.3 to 5.3.27 would make same code give syntax error?

Tags: php

What change from PHP version 5.2.3 to 5.3.27 would  make same code give syntax error? I have a PHP code which while it's fine on 5.2.3 it doesn't work on 5.3.27 and give the following error in the last line of code:

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in index.php on line
>   832

It doesn't make any sense to me but I don't do PHP coding a lot of  time. My question is if there's some syntax change or something like this which would make the syntax error.
Also, I'm using different servers Appserver and Vertrigo, if it's relevant.

**EDIT:**

In fact, the parser says that the error is on line 832 where the last line is 831. There's no extra `}` because if so it willn't run on the old version.

**EDIT2:**

Here's the last lines of code from actual program(it just doesn't work on recent PHP version):

```
<? } ?>

<?php 

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: Please post your actual code; we can't tell what might be an issue without it.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in index.php on line 832` seems like an extra `}` got added somewhere.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: more like lacking a `}`, causing a block to terminate early, e.g. `if(whatever) { <eof>`.

Comment: There are quite a few version between each release that you are using. The changes are listed. You can check out the changes here: http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php

Comment: Maybe it's a configuration change and [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) is differently configured.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch: Exactly that. Thanks. Post as answer to I accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it's a configuration change and [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) is differently configured.

Comment: This. Protip: try to avoid short open tags. Short echo tags (`<?=$test?>`) are somewhat okay.